# Is it possible to create a generic UserControl in SL3

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, silverlight-3.0, crud

I'm planning on creating a crud-screen with the folliwing template: on the left side there'll be a list of objects, and clicking on an object will bring up a screen for editing or adding it (it would probably have it's own Save button that would call the web service)

Since the same scenario can be used for many different objects, I would like to create a reusable control and then just pass it an object type. 
Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to look up "creating templateable silverlight controls".

Comment: Thank you!I read about it, but I still don't understand how I'd use it in the code behind. I would have define event handlers for my controls , but the only difference would just be the object type, so in C# that would act something like a generic class. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. I created a visual template, but what about code behind? How would I go around it?